# How to make a inline-block fit whole width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I won't to make an inline block fill whole the width. Actually I am using amp. I want to make all the fields fit the whole width. But I am unable to make it. I can do it using !important. But it is a bad practice. So how I can I do it without using !important? I am using the bellow code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script async custom-element="amp-autocomplete" src="https://www.cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-autocomplete-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async src="https://www.cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>

    <style>
        .page-form {
            background: url(https://mydoginsurance.com.au/images/form-bg-lg.webp) no-repeat center;
            background-size: cover;
            position: relative;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .section {
            padding: 63px 0;
        }

        .page-form .container {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 100;
        }

        .container, .container-fluid, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg, .container-xl {
            width: 100%;
            padding-right: 15px;
            padding-left: 15px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }

        .justify-content-center {
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .row {
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin-right: -15px;
            margin-left: -15px;
        }

        .col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col, .col-auto, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm, .col-sm-auto, .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md, .col-md-auto, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg, .col-lg-auto, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl, .col-xl-auto {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            padding-right: 15px;
            padding-left: 15px;
        }

        .text-center{
            text-align: center;
        }

        .mb-5, .my-5 {
            margin-bottom: 3rem;
        }

        h2, .h2 {
            font-size: 2.5rem;
        }

        .page-form .container .form-box {
            padding: 0;
            border: none;
            background: none;
            box-shadow: none;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        }

        .form-box {
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
            border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 13px 29px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 35%);
            box-shadow: 0 13px 29px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 35%);
            padding: 40px;
        }

        .justify-content-center {
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .form-box .mb-4 {
            position: relative;
        }

        .form-box .form-control {
            padding: 20px 0 0 18px;
            height: 54px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 2px;
            color: #000;
        }

        .form-control, input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=tel], input[type=file], input[type=search], textarea, select {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0.6rem 0.75rem;
            font-size: 1rem;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.5;
            color: #495057;
            background-color: #fff;
            background-clip: padding-box;
            border: 1px solid #ced4da;
            border-radius: 0rem;
            transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
        }

        [type="search"] {
            outline-offset: -2px;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="page-form section" id="getquote">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="mb-5 text-center">
                        <h2>Submit your Dog info and we'll address your request ASAP</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-box">
                        <form action="https://mydoginsurance.com.au/choose-plan.html" method="GET" target="_top">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="mb-4">
                                        <input type="text" name="dog_name" class="form-control" aria-labelledby="label_dog_name" required>
                                        <label id="label_dog_name" for="dog_name">Name of Dog</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="mb-4">
                                        <amp-autocomplete filter="substring" min-characters="0" style="padding: 0; color: black; display: cover">
                                            <input type="search" name="breed" class="form-control" id="tbdog" aria-labelledby="label_dog_breed" required>
                                            <label id="label_dog_breed" for="breed">Breed of Dog</label>
                                            <script type="application/json">
                                                { "items": [ "Affenpinscher", "Afghan Hound", "Airedale Terrier", "Akita" }
                                            </script>
                                        </amp-autocomplete>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="mb-4">
                                        <!--<input type="number" name="age" min="1" max="8" class="form-control" required>-->
                                        <select name="age" class="form-control" aria-labelledby="label_dog_age" required>
                                            <option></option>
                                            <option value="0">
                                                < 1 </option>
                                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <label id="label_dog_age" for="age">Age of Dog</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have hosted the site so that you can take a closer look to it: https://hungry-swanson-e6b32d.netlify.app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add width: 100% to it (the amp-autocomplete component)